# Node.js: remove specific columns from CSV file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a CSV file can contain around million records, how can I remove columns starting with _ and generate a resulting csv

For the sake of simplicity, consider i have the below csv

```
Sr.No Col1 Col2 _Col3   Col4 _Col5
1     txt  png  676766  win  8787
2     jpg  pdf  565657  lin  8787
3     pdf  jpg  786786  lin  9898
```

---

I would want the output to be

```
Sr.No Col1 Col2 Col4
1     txt  png  win 
2     jpg  pdf  lin 
3     pdf  jpg  lin
```

Do i need to read the entire file to achive this or is there a better approach to do this.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (row) => {
    // generate a new csv with removing specific column
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
  });
```

Any help on how can i achieve this would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone who stumbles on the post

I was able to transform the csv's using below code using `fs` and `csv` modules.

```
await fs.createReadStream(m.path)
      .pipe(csv.parse({delimiter: '\t', columns: true}))
      .pipe(csv.transform((input) => {
        delete input['_Col3'];
        console.log(input);
        return input;
      }))
      .pipe(csv.stringify({header: true}))
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(transformedPath))
      .on('finish', () => {
        console.log('finish....');
      }).on('error', () => {
        console.log('error.....');
      });
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/donmccurdy/6cbcd8cee74301f92b4400b376efda1d

Answer (score 1):

Try this with csv lib

```
const csv = require('csv');
const fs = require('fs');

const csvString=`col1,col2
               value1,value2`

csv.parse(csvString, {columns: true})
   .pipe(csv.transform(({col1,col2}) => ({col1}))) // remove col2
   .pipe(csv.stringify({header:true}))
   .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./file.csv'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can handle that by using two npm packages.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson
to convert your library to JSON format

then use this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

with the second library. If you know what are the exact fields you want. you can pass parameters to specifically select the fields you want.

```
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');
 
const fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
const opts = { fields };
 
try {
  const parser = new Parser(opts);
  const csv = parser.parse(myData);
  console.log(csv);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Or you can modify the JSON object manually to drop those columns

Comment: my file can be really big 500Mb or more. Looks like your solution is loading the entire data in memory which might result in program crashing, please correct if i am wrong

Comment: of course. If you load 500MB file to memory it might crash depending on your resource availability. but both those libraries provide a mechanism to use streaming, it's documentation. there you can use streaming methods. https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#use-stream https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv#json2csv-async-parser-streaming-api

Answer (score 0):

With this function I accomplished the column removal from a CSV

```
removeCol(csv, col) {
   let lines = csv.split("\n");
   let headers = lines[0].split(",");
   let colNameToRemove = headers.find(h=> h.trim() === col);
   let index = headers.indexOf(colNameToRemove);
   let newLines = [];
   lines.map((line)=>{
       let fields = line.split(",");
       fields.splice(index, 1)
       newLines.push(fields)
   })
   let arrData = '';
   for (let index = 0; index < newLines.length; index++) {
       const element = newLines[index];
       arrData += element.join(',') + '\n'
   }
   return arrData;
}
```